# Date.today and Date.yesterday are the same but not in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have looked at other questions asked regarding this topic but nothing seems to match what i have come across. I have 2 scopes that look for records from today and yesterday, but they both return exactly the same records.

```
scope :new_memberships_cash_today, ->() {
where(:start_date => Date.today)
joins(:membership).sum('memberships.cost')}

scope :new_memberships_cash_yesterday, ->() {
where(:start_date => Date.yesterday)
joins(:membership).sum('memberships.cost')}
```

When in the console Date.today and Date.yesterday return different values (ie today and yesterday)

The column start_date is a date field so this should work shouldn't it? has anyone come across this before?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get the same result when you run `scope :new_memberships_cash_today, ->() {where(:start_date => Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)}`

Comment: @Josh , yes I do get the same result

Comment: @zwippie, i have read that and tried the solution, but no joy either

Comment: is :start_date field date or datetime ?

Answer (score 19):

`Date.today` is not timezone aware, I believe `Date.yesterday` is timezone aware and `1.day.ago` definitely is.

Use `Date.current` in place of `Date.today` (same applies for `Time.now` - don't use it, use `Time.zone.now` or the shortcut method `Time.current`)

see http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails#cheat_sheet

I recommend reading that entire article as well as one I wrote recently - http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/